# Nationality API returning SQ as nationality

Tags: python, api, country-codes, country-json

I'm using 2 apis, being https://api.nationalize.io/?name= to guess someone's nationality from their name, and http://country.io/names.json to convert the two letter country code to a country name. This system works great, but while testing I noticed the name corrine returned SQ as the nationality. The api uses ISO 3166-1 alpha-2, but SQ doesn't represent any country in this system. Another naming system says it represents Albania, but Albania is returned as AL from the api. Please help

Test : https://api.nationalize.io/?name=corrine
Albania : https://api.nationalize.io/?name=Alteo

Tried looking for countries with SQ tag, but couldn't find any

Comment: What is your question? That API is out of stackoverflow's scope, the SQ tag seems to be [BCP-47 language code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IETF_language_tag), and you should not be getting the country name through an API for performance reason, this could be done using a dict.

Comment: Have you tried contacting the authors?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the SQ is wrong. The right result is SG, not SQ.

So, we can try to create conditional like this:

```js
fetch(`https://api.nationalize.io?name=corrine`)
  .then((res) => res.json())
  .then((data) => {
    const fixedResult = data.country
      ?.map((country) => {
        if (country.country_id === "SQ") {
          return { ...country, country_id: "SG" };
        } else {
          return country;
        }
      })
  console.log(fixedResult)
});
```

Anyway, you can check my project in the [nametionalize.vercel.app](https://nametionalize.vercel.app). Happy coding!